# Remove +Add New Product Category Link

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, product

In an effort to remove or hide this link in my WooCommerce product pages I have used the following css which were ineffective;

[image: Screenshot of my page]

```
.product_cat-add-toggle  {
    display: none;
}
```

**I have also tried**

```
#product_category-add-toggle {
    display: none;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

For both pieces of CSS, I tried adding `!important` but still had no success.

Comment: did you right click the link and inspect element to see how you could target it? it sounds like you were just guessing

Comment: Yes;     This is what was shown when I highlighted the link and inspected the element in google                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  <a id="product_cat-add-toggle" href="#product_cat-add" class="hide-if-no-js taxonomy-add-new">
     + Add New Product Category    </a>

Comment: maybe it has to do with `.hide-if-no-js` the js may be setting it to `display:block` though `#product_category-add-toggle {display: none !important;}` should override that which i believe you already tried.

Comment: Yes; I tried that with no results.  I am still in learning mode so I am not sure where to go next.  Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

try it in your theme functions.php

```
add_action('admin_head', 'my_custom_admin_style');

function my_custom_admin_style() {
  echo '<style>
    #product_category-add-toggle {display: none !important;}
  </style>';
}
```

Or

try to remove capability for the user to create a woocommerce new category for particular role

Comment: Thank you; I did  try this code in the functions php.  I forgot to mention in my original post that I did locate this code in this forum and it was not effective.   looking for ways to "remove capability for the user to create a woocommerce new category",  is the task at hand.  I appreciate your response.  Thanks again

Comment: install user role editor plugin and configure the capability.